# Problema de posision al crear custom QTooltip

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy tratando de crear una especie de `QTooltTip`, utilizando un `QLabel` para mostrar el mensaje.

En este caso de ejemplo trato de hacerlo con un `QPushButton` que al momento de que el mouse este sobre el muestre el `QLabel` a un lado del cursor.

Para lo cual instale un filtro de evento para poder detectar cuadno el mouse esta sobre el wigget;ya que mi intención es hacer esto con varios widgtes, dentro del filtro de evento si el evento es igual a `hover` entonces la función `mouseMoveEvent` se acciona y dentro de ella muestro el `QLabel` con el texto indicado.

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Hover.py", line 19, in eventFilter
    self.mouseMoveEvent(event)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Hover.py", line 23, in mouseMoveEvent
    print(event.globalPos())
AttributeError: 'QHoverEvent' object has no attribute 'globalPos'
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton,QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class Hover(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.customToolTip = QLabel(self)

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText("Button1")
        self.button.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self,object,event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print("Pressed")
            return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
            self.mouseMoveEvent(event)
            return True
        return False
    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        print(event.globalPos())
        self.customToolTip.setText("Otro texto")
        self.customToolTip.setStyleSheet("background:red;border-radius:5px;")
        self.customToolTip.move(event.globalPos()+QtCore.QPoint(5,5))
        self.customToolTip.adjustSize()
        self.customToolTip.show()



app = QApplication([])
h = Hover()
h.show()
h.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentalo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton,QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class Hover(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.customToolTip = QLabel(self)

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText("Button1")

        self.button.setMouseTracking(True)                            # +++
        self.setMouseTracking(True)                                   # +++

        self.button.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self,object,event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:                    # +++
            pos = event.pos()
            self.update_tooltip(pos)
            return True    
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverLeave:                 # +++
            print("HoverLeave")
            self.customToolTip.hide()
            return True          

        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print("Pressed")
            return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
#            self.mouseMoveEvent(event)                                # ---
            print("QEvent.HoverEnter:")
            return True

        return False

    def update_tooltip(self, pos):                                     # +++
        self.customToolTip.setText("  Otro texto  ")
        self.customToolTip.setStyleSheet('''background: red; 
                                            color: #fff;
                                            border-radius: 10px;
                                            min-height: 20px;
                                            max-height: 20px;
                                         ''')
        self.customToolTip.move(pos + QtCore.QPoint(5,30))
        self.customToolTip.adjustSize()
        self.customToolTip.show()    

#    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
#        print(event.globalPos())
#        self.customToolTip.setText("Otro texto")
#        self.customToolTip.setStyleSheet("background:red;border-radius:5px;")
#        self.customToolTip.move(event.globalPos()+QtCore.QPoint(5,5))
#        self.customToolTip.adjustSize()
#        self.customToolTip.show()


app = QApplication([])
h = Hover()
h.show()
h.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]